# unexpected behaviour of getchar

Tags: c, do-while, getchar

Just learning C programming, and stuck on what I'm sure is something trivial about Do/While loops. I have a block of code that requires the user to hit 'E' to exit the program:

```
char exitletter;

do {
printf ("Please hit E to exit the Program\n");
exitletter = getchar();
} while (exitletter !='E');
```

However, if the user enters an incorrect character, it prints "Please hit E to exit the Program" twice. If the user enters say abcd, it prints the message five times.

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: Handle the case where `exitletter` is `\n`.

Comment: To get the input to the programme, the user types a letter and <Return>, the newline remains in the input buffer to be immediately read in the second round.

Comment: Also the newline resulting from the "Return" press is a character, so it's dutifully reported by `getchar()`.

Comment: What happens if you *just* hit <enter>? Also, ask yourself how many characters are in your argument to `printf`? I count 34. Why?

Comment: Completing @DanielFischer's comment, you'd better read up to the next '\n' anyway: Whether the user types "E\n" or "End\n" or "Just go away!\n", you want to get rid of the full line. Perhaps the right trick is a `fgets(1)`, skip blanks and act accordingly. A `sscanf(line, "%c", &exitletter);` would fill most of the bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different answer though late:

You could have called `fflush` right after reading the character.

```
char exitletter;

    do {
        printf ("Please hit E to exit the Program\n");
        exitletter = getchar();
        fflush(stdin);
    } 
    while (exitletter !='E');
```

and this would have worked like you expected it to.

Answer (score 5):

That is because of the line feed character which entered during first `getchar`

Consider if you are pressing `N` and then pressing `enter` key to give input means. Actually you are entering two characters one is `N` and another is line feed character (`\n`). First `getchar` will read `N` from `stdin` and the line feed character remains in the `stdin` buffer itself. Now it will print the statment and then it will try to go for second `getchar` that time it will not wait for you to enter because one character is already available in `stdin` buffer, so it will read the line feed character then it will check with `E`, this time also loop will not break and it will print the statemnt and it will wait in 3rd `getchar` for user to enter input.

If the way of giving input to `getchar` is like typing that character and pressing enter key means, use the below logic which will help you to get rid of this problem.

```
do {
    printf ("Please hit E to exit the Program\n");
    exitletter = getchar();
    while(exitletter == '\n')exitletter = getchar();
} while (exitletter !='E');
```

Comment: that works great! how could I get rid of the problem of the user entering more than one character, and the message printing once per over entry?

Comment: user has to enter one character and `enter` key. If user are entering more than 1 characters, then write a looping logic to parse until `\n` and handle that case.